# iMacros script questions timeout/errormsg/popupignore etc

Tags: javascript, php, python, url, imacros

I have 1000+ URLs that I want to scrape to retrieve the title info from. After trying different things, I ultimately used iMacros scripts, which I don't know anything about. Nonetheless, I managed to make a script after reading guides.

My script is working perfectly but has few problem and have some queries

My Script:

```
VERSION BUILD=9002379
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO=http://google.com/
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TITLE ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=d:/ FILE=links.txt
WAIT SECONDS=1

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO=http://example.com:8087/
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TITLE ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=d:/ FILE=links.txt
```

what i want to ask is this

1- do i have to use SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1, SET !ERRORIGNORE YES, SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO for every URL or using these cmds on top only once will do?

2- even with SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO i get this error once https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKWQw.jpg in the begining, how to remove that??

3- out of many URLs i have a few that are dead so imacros wait till 60s before going to next url.. how to cut down the time to 10s for dead or non responding URLs?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN8FB.jpg  <-- how to make it 10s limit

4- the script i made is for 1 url. now how can i multiple this script 1000+ times all with different urls that i have in a specific txt file.
so either it makes this same script for all the urls or it auto leeches urls from a txt file while leeching like when first url is leeched it finds the next url from url txt file and auto inserts into this script so it can run all my urls and at the end i have results of all my urls

5- the final result i get is

> http://google.com,Google

how can i change is "," after URL to a tab or a double space so my results look something like this

> http://google.com     Google

kindly reply to all my queries and if possible redo my script so i would know where to put which code

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SET !DATASOURCE urls.txt
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10 
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TITLE ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET dblSP "  "
SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}{{dblSP}}{{!EXTRACT}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=d:\ FILE=links.txt
WAIT SECONDS=1
```

Play the above macro in loop mode with the ‘Max:’ value equal to the number of lines in your txt-file.

Comment: thanks for replying, but my problem isnt solved yet.. it is not taking urls from my url list instead it runs about.blank only

can data source be of text file? or csv oonly?
and u dint mentioned !urlcurrent command for leeching url title info which is the only thing i need..

Comment: You can use either csv-file or text file (with proper structure) in your macro. Test only the part of code for file reading and see what errors occur: `SET !DATASOURCE urls.txt` `SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}` `PROMPT {{!COL1}}` . And as I understood current urls are in your text file, therefore '!URLCURRENT' == '!COL1' .

Comment: I’ve updated my answer a little so that you can better understand the idea. (Note that the ‘urls.txt’ file is placed in the default ‘iMacros’ datasource folder.)

Comment: thanks, i did test it out and seems to be doing what i wanted to but have few issues.. 1- some urls are tested twice like if a url not responding it will finish its timeout and retries again till timeout, how to avoid that.. also some url pops up login id pw dialog box how to auto skip the site and dont stop our extraction processes meaning is id pw diaglog box appers it skips the site and moves on to next url

Comment: and Finally how to speed up the process like use 5-10 bots at a time to extract titles from that csv file

Comment: (1) I don’t know how to get rid of twice loading not seeing the error which causes that. (2) In order to auto skip the site and not to stop extraction processes when id & pw dialog box appears, try the `ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=CANCEL` command before `URL GOTO={{!COL1}}` . (3) Try to launch 5-10 instances of your browser and play macros after setting necessary starting point (e.g. `SET !LOOP 777`) and finishing one with the ‘Max:’ value for each of them.